# How do I disable "iTunes Home Sharing"?

Tags: itunes, security, preferences, bonjour

Whenever I launch iTunes, I see my computer appears listed among those offering Bonjour services (e.g., by iStumbler), with an entry for "iTunes Home Sharing" even though I have unchecked "Share my library on my local network" in iTunes preferences:

[image]

How do I *really* disable "iTunes Home Sharing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iTunes menus: File > Home Sharing > Turn Off Home Sharing

Comment: Wow (and Duh!) it looks like that did it. What does "Share my library on my local network" do then? How is it related to "Home Sharing"?

Comment: Home Sharing allows you to connect to your other computers and copy the music (so you can listen to it even if you are not connected on your network anymore) while sharing your libraries will only allow you to stream them to other computers on the same network.